# TCL More on Server Client

Tags: tcl

I am quite new to TCL and have been trying out the Server/Client example. I wanted to expand this a little further so that the server could send data to the client (which I managed if inserted at the "Echo" procedure: see code of example that I used). What I would like to do is in, for example, the "main function", call a procedure that will send data to the client without having to be in the "Echo" procedure.

```
# -------------------------------------------------------
# PROCEDURE Echo_server
# -------------------------------------------------------

proc Echo_server {port} {
    global echo
    global i
    set i 0
    set echo(main) [socket -server Echo_accept $port]
    vwait forever
}

# -------------------------------------------------------
# PROCEDURE Echo_accept
# -------------------------------------------------------

proc Echo_accept {sock addr port} {
    global echo
    puts "Accept $sock from $addr port $port, $echo(main)"
    set echo(addr,$sock) [list $addr $port]
    fconfigure $sock -buffering line
    fileevent $sock readable [list Echo $sock]
}

# -------------------------------------------------------
# SEND AND RECIEVE DATA.
# -------------------------------------------------------

proc Echo {sock} {
    global echo
    if {[eof $sock] || [catch {gets $sock line}]} {
        # end of file or abnormal connection drop
        close $sock
        puts "Client at $echo(addr,$sock) has disconnected."
        unset echo(addr,$sock)
    } else {
        if {[string compare $line "stop_new_conections"] == 0} {
            # Prevent new connections.
            # Existing connections stay open.
            puts $sock "Closing all other connections"
            puts "Client at $echo(addr,$sock) closed all incoming connections"
            close $echo(main)
        }
        puts "Client: \"$line\""
        set out [gets stdin]
        puts $sock $out
    }
}

# -------------------------------------------------------
# MAIN FUNCTION
# -------------------------------------------------------
Echo_server 5555
# here is where I would like to call a send proc that would send data to the client.
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send anything until a client connects and that is handled in the accept handler. You can use the socket's writable event (`fileevent $sock writable ...`) once you accept the client connection and once the socket becomes writable your handler can write something to the newly connected client.

Once you have sent the data to the connected client you should remove the writable fileevent using `fileevent $channel writable {}`. You should also check for connection errors in the writable event handler using `fconfigure $channel -error`. The [picoirc.tcl](https://github.com/tcltk/tcllib/blob/master/modules/irc/picoirc.tcl) code has some example of this in the Write procedure and there are others on the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/)

You can just write to the new connection in the accept function as well (ie: puts $sock "hello") in the Echo_accept function as well but it is generally better to use async io in Tcl servers as it is really quite simple and very effective.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the swift response. I didn't expect to get an answer, so I was pleased to see that this "forum" does work!
I managed to solve it yesterday by doing the following for the server. The client is practically the same thing. It works fine, but I use global variables (which I have just read that aren't too recomended) but for what it does, it kind of works!

```
set service_port  5555

proc accept_client_connection {channel_name address port} {
    global client_address
    global client_channel
    global client_port
    global connection
    fconfigure $channel_name -buffering none
    set client_channel $channel_name
    set client_address $address
    set client_port $port
    set connection 1
}

proc close_client_connection {} {
    global client_address
    close $client_address
}

proc Recieve_Data {} {
    global client_channel
    gets $client_channel msg
    # Confirm reception
    puts $client_channel "OK"
    return $msg
}

proc Send_Data {data} {
    global client_channel
    puts $client_channel $data
    gets $client_channel answer
    if { $answer != "OK" } {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

set server_sock [socket -server accept_client_connection $service_port]
vwait connection
puts "Connection established with client $client_channel with address: $client_address:$client_port\n"
set client_data [Recieve_Data]
puts "Client: \"$client_data\""
set data_to_send "HELLO CLIENT!"
while { ! [ Send_Data $data_to_send ] } {
    puts "Error sending data to server..."
    after 1000
}

vwait forever
```